# Is it possible to shootdodge without going into bullet time?

Tags: pc, max-payne

"Shootdodge" is a core feature in Max Payne, allowing the character to dive through air in slow motion. There is a key binding in the control options for "shootdodge only"—because bullet time is a finite resource which doesn't automatically recharge, diving in real-time would be a great way to move behind cover and gain distance. Max Payne simulates bullet ballistics and evading is always feasible. However, the "shootdodge only" move also enables bullet time as does "bullet time combo" and I can't notice any difference between these features. Both trigger the shootdodge move and enable bullet time, disabling it when Max lands.

I doubt that the game has two identical key bindings. I'm sure that my mouse has the corresponding buttons (MB 2-4) and that I'm hitting the correct keys. "Bullet time only" solely enables slow motion, as described. Game version is [1.05](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/466-max-payne-patch/).

[image: keybindings]

Comment: If I remember right from Max Payne 2, the only way to dive was without the slow motion was to be out of bullet time.  I'm wondering if it is the same here.

Comment: @TimmyJim: Max doesn't seem to perform the shootdodge move when out of bullet time, it is more of a "standard dodge" and he doesn't gain much air.

Comment: Might be a difference between Max Payne 1 and 2.  It's hard to tell, but [the Wiki](http://maxpayne.wikia.com/wiki/Shootdodge#) page for shootdodge for Max Payne 1 makes it sound like it's possible to do it without triggering bullet time.

Comment: I'ts been decades since I've played this but I believe the trick I used was dive and then switch bullet time off. If you're fast enough you don't loose that much at all.

Comment: @ИвоНедев: I wasn't able to switch bullet time off during diving, I tried both keybindings and hammered all three buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but it is possible to perform a rolling dodge by selecting a direction with a movement key and pressing "jump". Max can't shoot during the duration of the move and is unable dash forward (likely because the key combination would overlap with the standard jump), unlike in shootdodge.

Answer (score 0):

Press the bullet time button during a shoot dodge to go back to normal speed.